# Trigger mysql between sessions

Tags: triggers

I want to know the answer to this question before knowing if I need to set up a trigger or not:

After I create a mysql trigger for a table. If there was two people on my site, one was inserting something into the database, will the second one on my site execute the function I specified for that trigger also or will only the one who inserted get the trigger function executed?

Answer (score 1):

Triggers are only executed on INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE operations.

If you define a trigger to be executed when something is inserted in a specified table, then it will be executed only when an `INSERT` happens on this table.

Each MySQL query is run by a specific MySQL session. If 2 users are visiting the same web page, and only the first user inserts something in the table, then the trigger will be run only by the MySQL session opened by the first user.

Documentation: [CREATE TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html)

Comment: I was asking if this can happen across multiple connections also. What I visited the page and you were also on this page and you inserted something into the database. Will The function for the trigger be executed in my browser also since you added something to the database? Or will it only be executed on your browser since it is you who inserted the row in the database. You didn't answer my question.

Comment: I think I did reply to your question: a connection that doesn't insert something in the table doesn't execute the triger.

Comment: Can you tell me what I should use to get what I wanted to do? ( I want it to be across multiple sessions )